# How to effect website using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi i've been looking at lots of tutorials and can't find anything it might be my poor google skills but I hoped the answer was quick and simple.

**The Plan**

The aim is to make an extension which will append any website using javascript.

**Current State**

I current have the javascript append coded and basic manifesto created

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="adBar" style="background-color: #933131; width: 150px; height: 400px; position: fixed; left: 10px; top: 25%;"></div>'
```

**The Problem**

I can't find anywhere how to create a chrome extension which would allow this script to run in the background on every page, I can only find how to make a pop-up on click.

I hope this is clear and simple. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that this code will utterly destroy any page since it will break all event handlers. Don't use `innerHTML`.

Comment: @xan What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Create an element, set its properties and append it to body element.

Comment: @Xan Ok, im not sure how to do that using pure Java script, what about jQuery $(document).ready then $(body).append();?

Comment: If you're willing to include jQuery with your script, it's viable to use `append`. I would recommend researching how to do it with pure JS, it's not hard. As a starting point, `document.createElement`

Comment: @Xan like this? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `matches` to `<all_urls>` (also you can add a button to the extension to trigger it). Here is my full example:

[Extension Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQFjG.png)

```
My Extension
├── manifest.json
├── background.js
├── content.js
├── jquery-2.2.0.min.js
├── icon.png
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["jquery-2.2.0.min.js","content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png" 
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {

        //YOUR CODE GOES HERE

    }
  }
);
```

Basically I added a button to the extension that calls the `content.js` once it is pressed. The listener is on `background.js`.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer!

Comment: Adding the jQuery into the content script, I'm guessing allows me to code in jQuery changing my Javascript to something like $("body").append();

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the code in [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and use "all_urls" for match patterns.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

content.js

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="adBar" style="background-color: #933131; width: 150px; height: 400px; position: fixed; left: 10px; top: 25%;"></div>'
```